# Reload Method or Object in IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

when using idle, I know you can reload a module if it's changed like this:

```
import foo
reload(foo)
```

if I  only import part of a module, is there a way to reload it in a similar matter?

```
from foo import bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `reload` has to re-run the whole module.

Note that `reload` is confusing and does not have the ability to be consistent. It's much better to restart the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll have to import foo, then reload(foo), after all.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload

It says:

> "If a module imports objects from another module using from ... import
>   ..., calling reload() for the other module does not redefine the
>   objects imported from it — one way around this is to re-execute the
>   from statement, another is to use import and qualified names
>   (module.*name*) instead."

But the statements is not very clear.